# I want to route to a new web page after a post of data

Tags: javascript, python, flask, post

I have this route defined and while the render_template has worked for me before, I can't seem to figure out why the web page stays on the existing page.  I sure it hits and processes all of the way through, as I have returned a 200, Ok and received back on the javascript side.  I even tried to redirect to processes the request as a GET and allow the get to render_template, but still no luck.  Any ideas?

Route code

```
@app.route("/view", methods=["GET","POST"])
@cross_origin()
def view_playlist():
    global playlist_item
    if request.method == 'POST':
        playlist_item = request.get_json()
        print("playlist POST")
        return render_template('/view.html', result= playlist_item)
        # return redirect(url_for('view_playlist'))
    else:
        print("This is a GET")
        return render_template('/view.html', result= playlist_item)
        # app.send_static_file("index.html", result= playlist_item)
```

The javascript post is as follows

```
        
      url = local + '/view'
      fetch(url,{
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST',

        body:JSON.stringify(itemsPlaylist)
    
    }).then(function(data) {

      // location.replace(local + '/view.html');
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code can't think of any obvious reasons, but worth printing the response in then and also put in a catch block.

You could also use finally to do the routing

```
fetch(myRequest)
.then(function(response) {})
.catch(function(error) { console.error(error); })
.finally(function() { .. do the routing here });
```